# c++ Making one std::string to another

Tags: c++, string, pointers

As you probably would be able to tell from my question,, I'm a c++ newbie

I'm not sure what's the right way to copy one string's value to another..

For instance I did this:

```
std::string x = "this is x";
std::string y = "this is y";
x = y;
```

No error,, but this does not do anything..

I know there is string::copy... but seems like this function needs buffer size, etc.. which is annoying..

Is there a simple way to do this job in c++?

Thanks

**UPDATE!!**

Sorry,, I think I simplified my answer too much.....
This is my situation:

```
class MyClass {
    std::string m_str = "OLD STRING";
}

void CopyString(MyClass& c, std::string x) {
    c.m_str = x;
}

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    CopyString(c, "NEW STRING");

    std::cout << c.m_str << std::endl;           // prints "OLD STRING"!!
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that doesn't do anything? Show proof that it doesn't.

Comment: @chris sorry! I updated my question

Comment: Decent c++ classes do the memory management internally - std::string is a decent class.

Comment: That's definitely not the exact code, but with adding the semicolon and making `m_str` accessible, [it prints the new string](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f62b114120f1fa3).

Comment: @chris what the.. thanks anyway .. I don't even know what the hell I am asking either

Comment: @DieterLücking: well, i've always thought of `std::string` as an indecent class. just my 2c.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yep, it lost the the focus on data and has too many functions

Answer (score 5):

Your code

```
std::string x = "this is x";
std::string y = "this is y";
x = y;
```

is correct, and copies the value of the `y` variable, to the `x` variable.

Your assertion

> **”** this does not do anything.

is – happily – incorrect.

Comment: sorry! I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

when you do `x = y`, it will copy the value of `y` into `x`, thus, make `x` will be `this is y`

Comment: sorry! I updated my question

Comment: Like Christ has pointed out. The code should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

All though its not the best implementation (get/set methods would be better), you need to make m_str public. When using a class, if you don't set it differently all variables are set to private by default. Change it to this and it should compile and run.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::string m_str = "OLD STRING";
};
```

EDIT: you also forgot your semicolons at the end of your class and copy methods.